# Unwanted newline after a tcolorbox

Tags: line-breaking, tcolorbox

How to avoid new line jump after each tcolorbox ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,luacode,array,tcolorbox,bm,geometry}

\geometry{margin=1.5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{luacode}
function Table (n)
    for i=1,10
    do
        tex.print(i.."&\\bm{"..n.."}&"..i*n.."\\\\")
    end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\Table}[1]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=.18\linewidth,colback={white},
        title={\textbf{\vphantom{Éq}%
        \Large\hfill\textsf{Table de #1}\hfill\strut}},%
        colbacktitle=gray!75,coltitle=white,
        left=1mm,top=1mm,right=1mm,bottom=1mm]
    \large
    \hfill$\begin{array}{r@{\;$\times$\;}c@{\;=\;}r}
        \directlua{Table(#1)}
    \end{array}$\hfill\strut
    \end{tcolorbox} bob}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {\Table{\i}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with the option `nobeforeafter` --- worked for me. Maybe with the `hbox` option too.

Comment: Ok for me. Thank you. Consider to write an answser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally `tcolorbox` try to typeset the box as a paragraph; to do that sets the keys `before` and `after` to a value that is dependent on the presence or not of the package `parskip` (guessed, really). Typically they are something like:

```
before={\par\pagebreak[0]\smallskip\parindent=0pt}, after={\par\smallskip}
```

If you want to clear the default values, use the key `nobeforeafter`; in the manual (pag. 78 in my copy, version 4.12) it states:

> Abbreviation for clearing the keys before and after. The colored box
>   is not put into a paragraph and there is no space before or after the
>   box.

Moreover, the option `hbox` is needed sometime; this will size the box according to the content (and no the other way around; pag. 94):

> `capture=hbox:` This is the default mode for `\tcbox`. The content
>   cannot have a lower part and cannot be broken. The colored box is
>   sized according to the dimensions of the content. A shortcut to set
>   this mode is `/tcb/hbox`.

Comment: This worked for me: `\begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter, ...] ... \end{tcolorbox}`

Comment: @normanius yes, as I wrote in the second paragraph... 

Comment: Yes, I followed your instructions, but I added the example for those that do not recall what a key is.